# SQL Server trigger on two different database server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have two different database server on two different IP addresses. Say `SERVER_1` and `SERVER_2` (SQL Server 2012).

How to write trigger on table from `SERVER_1` database and `insert` record in `SERVER_2` table ?

Comment: Whether both the servers are linked ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want to use trigger to insert on different server,you also can use replication if you want to keep data upto date..The approach you are using has disadvantage,since for every insert ,this query has to insert on a different server..

if you want to use trigger,use it like below

```
create trigger trg_test
on dbo.yourtable
after insert 
as
begin

insert into server2.databasename.schemaname.tablename
select * from server1.databasename.schemaname.table

end
```

Answer (score 1):

First Create Link server between 2 server using below command and use the code which is given above.

sp_addlinkedserver 'Server1' or sp_addlinkedserver 'Server2'